# Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager installation

Tags: android, virtual-machine, haxm

i have problem with installation this software, i  need it for using Android studio simulators. I get this error.

[image]

I check this Hyper-V -> it's unchecked

I enabled in Bios Virtualization technology.

I disabled Avira RT protection.

I tried  *cold boot*.

And i still get this
[image]

I'm using W10(x64) , Processor: AMD A10-4600M.

Comment: Processor: AMD A10-4600M.  <---  switch to intel and then HAXM will work.  Or switch to genymotion

Answer (score 0):

The SDK Manager will download the installer to the "extras" directory, under the main SDK directory. Even though the SDK manager says "Installed" it actually means that the Intel HAXM executable was downloaded. You will still need to run the installer from the "extras" directory to finish installation.

Extract the installer inside the "extras" directory and follow the installation instructions for your platform."

Answer (score 0):

HAXM does not work on AMD processors.